# 70s-2000s anime with magic bracelets

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've been looking for an anime for a while now. The main character is a girl who arrives at a college. I remember this girl playing baseball with the other students and stopping a ball with her hand using her powers (at that time she was not really aware of her powers). I also remember the main antagonist, he has blue hair and he uses a bracelet by putting a blue stone on it, and he fights with it. When he puts the stone, the bracelet opens, as if he had wings (it looks like a small airplane on his wrist). The girl also uses a bracelet and that's basically the battles. I don't have any more info and hope someone remembers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? And what colour was the girl's hair?